# Overriding Bean Configuration with annotations

Tags: spring, annotations, classpath, overriding, spring-annotations

Use case: I have my container configured via classpath scanning @ComponentScan.  For my test configuration I need the ability to mock specific beans.

Due to the order of loading, beans loaded via classpath scan are not overriding properly when using @Configuration.  The following code samples demonstrate the problem.  BaseExample.java shows how it is possible to override beans via configuration.  ScanExample.java shows that overriding a bean that was loaded via @ComponentScan is skipped (see final note).

A demo project is available on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/dcompiled/spring-override-bug).

```
// BaseExample.java

package com.glassworks.mock;

import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;

public class BaseExample {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseExample.class);
    private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class, OverrideConfig.class);

        String beans[] = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        log.info("{} beans found: {}", beans.length, Joiner.on(",").join(beans));

        for(String bean : beans) {
            log.info("{}: {}", bean, ctx.getBean(bean));
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class Config {
        @Bean
        public AccountDao accountDao() {
            log.debug("Creating accountDao [Config]");
            return new AccountDao();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class OverrideConfig {
        @Bean
        public Object accountDao() {
            log.debug("Creating accountDao [OverrideConfig]");
            return Mockito.mock(AccountDao.class);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:
21:05  INFO | com.glassworks.mock.BaseExample                    | accountDao: Mock for AccountDao, hashCode: 666537607

```
[// ScanExample.java

package com.glassworks.mock;

import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;

public class ScanExample {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScanExample.class);
    private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class, OverrideConfig.class);

        String beans[] = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        log.info("{} beans found: {}", beans.length, Joiner.on(",").join(beans));

        for(String bean : beans) {
            log.info("{}: {}", bean, ctx.getBean(bean));
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("com.glassworks.services")
    public static class Config {

    }

    @Configuration
    public static class OverrideConfig {
        @Bean
        public AccountDao accountDao() {
            log.debug("Creating accountDao [OverrideConfig]");
            return Mockito.mock(AccountDao.class);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:
21:08  INFO | com.glassworks.mock.ScanExample                    | accountDao: com.glassworks.services.AccountDao@48805ebb

```
// AccountDao.java
package com.glassworks.services;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class AccountDao {

}
```

**Note**
Its worth noting on that with logging set to debug, Spring indicates that it is skipping over the definition.  This appears to be a bug.

21:09 DEBUG | o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader     | Skipping loading bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=accountDao,declaringClass=com.glassworks.mock.ScanExample$OverrideConfig]: a definition for bean 'accountDao' already exists. This is likely due to an override in XML.

Comment: Is your question 'Is this a bug?'?

Comment: It is kind of a BUG. see https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9682 how did you solve it?